# Trouble changing the text of a label in .net using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

There seems to be lots of examples of how to do this but every one I try results in failure or unhandledexception error. 
Anyway here it goes:
here is the jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".MyMenu a").each(function (index) {
            $(this).click(function () {
                var htmlString = $(this).html();
                $(this).text(htmlString);
                alert(htmlString);
                var g = $('#<%=lblProject.ClientID%>').text(htmlString);
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

I've tried changing the web.config for ClientIDMode and every way I change this my page blows up with 
Global Page Error
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the actual exception and/or stack trace?

Comment: I guarantee you its gibberish and is not of any use

Comment: Ok I've changed it from #<%=lblProject.ClientID%> to '#lblProject').text and it sort of works